# Question regarding 上がったり

Tags: set-phrases

Why does 上がったり mean doomed business etc. even if in 上がったり下がったり it means going up/improving (as does 上がる)?

Is it shortened from a longer phrase or something?
Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the sense that 上がったり means "doomed business"?  Could you provide any context, or the source you used?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi they're referring to this word https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A

Comment: @Leebo, thanks, ya, but that doesn't refer to a "doomed business" -- on its own, the noun sense is more like "doomed-ness", as I understand it.  Without knowing more about where Jack encountered the term, it's hard to know how to address the question.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I think that's just how it shows up in E-J dictionaries

Comment: @Leebo, for what English source term?

Comment: I'm guessing Jack looked at this https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A and got "doomed business" from it, when it's like "doomed (of a business)" in that entry.

Comment: yeah its as Leebo said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One meaning of あがる is something along the lines of "to be finished," "to be over," "to stop functioning," etc.

This is the meaning used in 商売が上がったりだ。

"Up" can have a similar meaning in English, such as in the sentence "My contract is up in 3 weeks." It's not negative here, but the meaning of "over" is there.